# Understanding and using incremental regression with catboost

Tags: machine-learning, catboost, catboostregressor, incremental

I saw the example ([Catboost training model for huge data(~22GB) with multiple chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47019215/catboost-training-model-for-huge-data22gb-with-multiple-chunks/63888635#63888635)) for classification with catboost and tried to adapt it to for incremental multiple regression but I keep spinning my wheels with it generating different errors that are not clear.

```
from catboost import CatBoostRegressor
from catboost import Pool
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

clf = CatBoostRegressor(task_type="CPU",
                     iterations=1000,
                     loss_function='MultiRMSE',
                     learning_rate=0.5,
                     max_depth=7)
chunk=pd.read_csv('./train2/DataTableTrain.tsv',sep='\t',chunksize=10000000)
for i,ds in enumerate(chunk):
    X = Pool(ds, column_description='./train-7-7.cd', delimiter='\t');
    if i==0:
        clf.fit(X, column_description='./train-7-7.cd')
    else:
        clf.fit(X, init_model='model.bin',
                column_description='./train-7-7.cd')
    clf.save_model('model.bin')         # save model so is loaded in the next step
    del X
```

The column description file looks as follows:

```
0       Label
1       Label
2       Label
3       Label
4       Label
5       Label
6       Label
7       Num
8       Num
9       Num
10      Num
11      Num
12      Num
13      Num
```

The data file is 14 tab separated string representations of numbers per line.

Currently it is complaining about 'data should be the string or pathlib.Path type if column_description parameter is specified.' Can someone please direct me to what the software wants or provide a sample python application that can incrementally process a file for multiple regression.

Also, can you explain what incremental means in the context of training? For examples that I have tried successfully, the model seems to just have a new model tacked on to the end for each chunk